Discourse similarity techniques, beyond LSA
I want to think of a methodology that would claim two “discourses” are “equivalent” or fuzzily equivalent in form.
I think this requires some sort of semantic parse where you choose very precisely what categories are constructed from the input textual data.
I am wondering what techniques there are for this.
I’m thinking of using some very straightforward machine learning technique which discovers salient features in data, allowing you to select the ones it retrieves that you prefer as relevant. Thinking of exploring this.
I’d really appreciate some input from someone who knows computational linguistics.

Discourse is not an easy thing to define. It has more than one meaning.
